# Formatting output for ArrayList using an iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, formatting

I'm having issues with formatting my output for my Java program using an external file feeding into an ArrayList and then using an Iterator to produce the output. I created a text comma delimited file with the below data.

amphibian,frog,green,swims
mammal,dog,brown,runs
bird,falcon,brown,flies
fish,salmon,silver,swims

it gets loaded into the program and then needs to use an iterator to print out the output. The issue I'm having is trying to get each element in the array to print into a column. Output currently looks like below. Any help on how to format this is greatly appreciated.

### Type        Name        Color       Action

amphibian,frog,green,swims
mammal,dog,brown,runs
bird,falcon,brown,flies 
fish,salmon,silver,swims

```
public class AnimalIO {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("animals.txt");

    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    String animal;

    // Structure used to read external data into internal ArrayList
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            animal = input.nextLine();
            animals.add(animal);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("The input file \"animals.txt\" was not found.");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    System.out.print("Type\t\tName\t\tColor\t\tAction\n");
    System.out.print("---------------------------------------------------"
                     + "----\n");

    // Iterator structure used to print file
    Iterator aio = animals.iterator();
    while (aio.hasNext()){
        Object element = aio.next();
        System.out.print(element + "\t\n");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `System.out.printf` instead or `System.out.print`. You can probably check [this](http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf) out to see examples of the same. You may set specific width of all columns larger than the largest size data in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Using the split action with comma separator will do to further split the row array element.

```
Iterator aio = animals.iterator();
while (aio.hasNext()){
    String rowElement = (String) aio.next();
    String[] atomicElement = rowElement.split(",");
    // do something
}
```